# How to determine the selected element while using multiple selectors in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am writing a simple fade-slideshow with a two `next` and `previous` buttons.

(Using semantic-ui's buttons)

```
    <div id="slides_container">
        <div id="slide0" class="slide_image"><img src="images/slide0.png" alt=""></div>
        <div id="slide1" class="slide_image"><img src="images/slide1.png" alt=""></div>
        ...
    </div>
    <div id="slides_counter_container">
        <div class=" ... transition_button" id="previous_button">...</div>
        <div id="slides_counter"></div>
        <div class=" ... transition_button" id="next_button">...</div>
    </div>
```

I want to handle both cases of pressing `next` or `previous` button in one jQuery click-event.

```
$(".transition_button").click(function (){
    ...
    $("#slide"+current_slide).fadeOut(FADE_DURATION, function () {
        var temp = $(this).attr("id");
        if (temp == "next_button"){
            ...
            // current_slide ++
        }
        else{
            ...
            // current_slide --
        }
        // fadeIn() new current_slide
    });
});
```

By using `$(this).attr("id")` I will get one of these id s: `slide0` or `slide1` or ... (depending on the current slide number, which isn't related to the `next or previous` buttons at all!

- What's the problem?
- How can we specifically find the `div` `button` `anchor`, etc, which caused a multiple selector event, to be fired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**what is the problem?**

you are getting id inside `fadeOut` callback function here right now `$(this)` is reffers to  `.slide_image` which is slider div element not the clicked element

```
 $(".transition_button").click(function (){
  //move temp here 
 var temp = $(this).attr("id");
$("#slide"+current_slide).fadeOut(FADE_DURATION, function () {

    if (temp == "next_button"){
        ...
        // current_slide ++
    }
    else{
        ...
        // current_slide --
    }
    // fadeIn() new current_slide
  });
});
```